# Subtracting time period

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, calendar, subtraction

I'm with the following problem:

I have two variables called "hourOne" and "hourTwo" of type Calendar[][]. They have periods of dates stored in two columns, "start" and "end". I need subtract the hours to find the differences and store in another variable (hourThree for example) like this

```
hourOne[0][0] = "08:00"
hourOne[0][1] = "12:00"

hourTwo[0][0] = "07:00"
hourTwo[0][1] = "13:00"
```

In hourThree will have

```
hourThree[0][0] = "07:00"
hourThree[0][1] = "08:00"
hourThree[1][0] = "12:00"
hourThree[1][1] = "13:00"
```

How can I subtract this periods?

Detail: I can't use JodaTime API for this, and the variables don't have a defined number of rows (one may have more lines than the other too).

Comment: @bhdrkn have you read last sentence from question?

Answer (score 0):

use SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
ParsePosition idx = new ParsePostion(0);
long time = sdf.parse(hourOne[0][0], idx).getTime() - sdf.parse(hourOne[0][1], idx).getTime();
```

Comment: But with this I will take the time(One hour for example)... I want to subtract the periods and put the left period in a third variable as I did in the example

Answer (score 0):

as solution passed by @ControllAltDel is strongly recommended,
if you dont want to play with Dateformat, you could implement simple method for time arthmetics, based on this

```
static String sub (String a,String b){
    String[] tmp = a.split(":");
    int ah = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
    int am = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);
    tmp = b.split(":");
    int bh = Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]);
    int bm = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]);

    int cm = am-bm;
    int reminder = 0;

    cm=cm%60;
    if (cm<0) {
        reminder--;
            cm+=60;
    }

    int ch = ah-bh+reminder;
    return ch+":"+cm;
}
```